# How can I add channels to subscribe to futures_multiplex_socket to libraries binance?

Tags: python, asynchronous, ws

Good day to all, I have an application that connects WS binance and receives ohlcv in real time. After a certain logic, she issues an order. I want the function to also receive the change status of this order via the '12324235@orderUpdate' channel. As far as I could understand from the documentation it is possible, it is enough to add a channel with an order id to subscriptions. That is, if I knew the order ID at the time of calling the function, it would look something like this:

> ts = bsm.futures_multiplex_socket(['btcusdt@kline_1m',
> '12324235@orderUpdate'])

However, I don't know that. can you tell me how I can add a listening channel to the current WS or do I need to close the connection and open it already with new parameters? how do I do this?

My app skillet looks like this

```
import asyncio
from binance import AsyncClient, BinanceSocketManager


async def main():
    client = await AsyncClient.create()
    bsm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
    ts = bsm.futures_multiplex_socket(['btcusdt@kline_1m'])
    async with ts as tscm:
        while True:
            stream_binance = await tscm.recv()
            if stream_binance['stream'] == 'btcusdt@kline_1m':
                print('ohlcv processed')

    while True:
        print('place an order')
        # Here I put up a new order
        # I know his ID and I know the channel you need to subscribe to in order to receive status updates on the order
        # for example "123456@orderUpdate"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I also found several examples of how to do this one of them tells me:

```
from binance.client import Client
from binance.websockets import BinanceSocketManager

# API credentials
api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
api_secret = 'YOUR_API_SECRET'

# Create Binance client and socket manager instances
client = Client(api_key, api_secret)
bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)

# Define the callback function to handle order updates
def handle_order_update(msg):
    print("Order Update:")
    print(msg)
    # Process the order update information here

# Start the WebSocket connection and get the connection key
conn_key = bm.start_multiplex_socket(callback=handle_order_update, streams=['btcusdt@kline_1m'])

# Add a subscription event for order changes with a specified ID
order_id = '12345678'
stream_to_add = f"{order_id.lower()}@orderUpdate"
bm.start_socket(callback=handle_order_update, stream_name=stream_to_add)

# Remove the subscription event for order changes with the specified ID
stream_to_remove = f"{order_id.lower()}@orderUpdate"
bm.stop_socket(conn_key, stream_name=stream_to_remove)

# Keep the script running to receive order updates
bm.start()
```

However, the start_socket/stop_socket function is no longer in the library, perhaps this example is quite old.